# GKE Konnectivity agent writes to closed connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubelet

Since GKE upgraded to 1.21.10-gke.2000 I see these errors in the konnectivity-agent logs every 5 minutes or so. I cannot detect any consequences to these problems, but I cannot get them to go away either. Does anyone know what the problem is and how I get it to go away?

```
pod_name: "konnectivity-agent-779eadf84d-98kjh"

"conn write failure" err="write tcp 10.48.0.2:40528->10.48.0.8:10250: use of closed network connection" connectionID=215
"connection read failure" err="read tcp 10.48.0.2:40528->10.48.0.8:10250: use of closed network connection"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error when the liveness probe is timing out. Try lengthening the timeoutSeconds on your livenessProbe and see if the problem goes away.

Refer this [link](https://github.com/openshift/hypershift/issues/313) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the below:
Adding  a firewall egress rule that allow you to connect to the port (use the port number getting displayed in the error message with the IP of the end point) , you could use the following command to add that rule. that should allow the konnectivity-agent to connect to the control plane.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create gke-node-to-konnectivity-service \
--allow=tcp:<port number> \
--direction=EGRESS \
--destination-ranges=<endpoint IP address > \
--target-tags=< node name> \
--priority=1000
```

Am using gke version 1.21.11. But did not work though

Comment: Hi, how can you handle this in case of auto scaling where you have a lot of nodes? Also, what is the endpoint IP address you mentioned? Is it the IP of the master?

Comment: Hi, the above is not working for me as expected